# Prevent duplicate copy paste in excel

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, validation

Hi all the noob is back again. I am doing a copy paste job of data from one worksheet into another which is hidden but there is a danger that data will be duplicated if not checked against what has already been pasted. So far, what I have done is to insert a code in the worksheet I am copying to, to stop the duplication but the complication I now have is that the validation is checking every bit of data throughout the column from start to end and this is about 5000< entries. Column B has the report date which is the same for all entries belonging to the same month end. So it will have say 5000 entries with 30/1/13....another with 28/02/13 etc. Ideally, I want to only check once in Column B where the report date is entered and if the date matches to what I want to copy, then reject the entire copy paste process instead of validating each individual entry in the copy range. Here is the code I am working with. I hope I'm making sense & thank you very much for helping.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ans As String
    Const myCol As Long = 2

    If Intersect(Target, Columns(myCol)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each r In Intersect(Target, Columns(myCol))
        If Application.CountIf(Columns(myCol), r.Value) > 1 Then
            MsgBox (r.Value & " already exsists")
            r.ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

thats my code including the remove duplicates but it aint working. I have tried it

```
Sub LoadData_toTable()
Dim ws1LRow As Long, ws2LRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW DATA")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA INPUT")
       With ws1
        ws1LRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=.Range("A1"), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row + 1

        End With
            With ws2
                    ws2LRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    .Range("A2:AR" & ws2LRow).Copy
                    ws1.Range("A" & ws1LRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            End With
                With ws1
                ws1.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates
            End With
            For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
            PT.RefreshTable
        Next PT
    Next WS

 MsgBox "Loading month's data complete!"
End Sub
```

Comment: If it is just the duplication that you are worried about then instead of matching every entry, Let the user paste the duplicate entries. When the pasting is done, simply use one line `.RemoveDuplicates` to remove the duplicates. That would be much faster... Which Excel version are you using? EDIT: See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238869%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: I am using excel 2007 and have tried the remove duplicates but won't work.

Comment: And why do you feel it won't work?

Comment: I have appended the code with the remove duplicates line but its still not working.

Comment: In your try below you need to use `ws1.Range("A:AR").RemoveDuplicates` to remove duplicates from ALL columns, not just `A:A`

Comment: Again no joy. Is there a way say of adding a script at the beginning of the code, checking Ws1 Row B last cell and compare to Ws2 Row B2 and if that returns a match do a message to say already exists.

Answer (score 0):

A very-long-calculation-time-solution would be to create an array containing only data not equal to that already in the sheet (you would have to iterate each copied element and compare to each element in the hidden sheet).

Otherwise you could format the duplicated data in some way, then iterate and remove all the formatted data except the first (which you would re-format as before). Example:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0 ""double"""  '<--- this could be made also with colors
Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
ExecuteExcel4Macro "(2,1,""0.0 ""double"""")"
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Then inside iteration

```
cells(x,y).select

if counted_formatted_data = 1 then
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0 " '<--- back to the previous formatting
else
    selection.delete
end if
```

Of course it is better if you do this without selecting anything.